# How to type a property in a interface according to keys of another property has unknown structure in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript

I used a module can do such thing

```
function print(obj, key) {
  console.log(obj[key])
}

print({'test': 'content'}, '/* vs code will show code recommendation when typing */')
```

I want to have this feature but I forgot the name of the module and I even don't sure if I misremembered (maybe it's impossible).

I'm working on a package and have a code like this:

```
interface Box {
  content: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  using: string // key of content 
}

const box: Box = {
  content: {
    'something': 'inside'
  },
  using: 'something'
}

function showBox(box: Box) {
  console.log(box.content[box.using])
}
```

Actually the `content` is a object comes from another package using typescript. I would like not to wrap the type if possible.

To help devs can find bugs during coding, I'm looking for if there is a way to check invalid `Box` type like:

```
const box: Box = {
  content: {
    'something': 'inside'
  },
  using: 'samething' // raise error when checking type
}
```

Or any way can make code recommendation of IDE know the `using` should be a key of `content` object.

My code currently looks like this but it's not what I want, and I don't have any idea to go on

```
interface Box {
  content: {
    [key: string]: string
  }
  using: keyof Box['content'] // will be string | number
}
```

Thanks to all response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution is actually correct, but IDE cannot suggest you anything because `keyof Box['content']` is typed to be an arbitrary string. If you know that `content` should always have some specific structure, you can just put it inside `Box` description like this:

```js
interface Box {
  content: {
    something: string;
  };
  // now it only allowed to be 'something', and IDE will suggest it
  using: keyof Box['content'];
}
```

If your `content`'s type is actually a parameter (meaning that you can have boxes for arbitrary types), you should make it a parameter for `Box` interface, thus making it a generic interface:

```js
interface GenericBox<T> {
    content: T;
    using: keyof T;
}
```

Now you can use it like this:

```js
// simple example interface to fill a box
interface TestContent {
    x: string;
    y: number;
}

const genericBox: GenericBox<TestContent> = {
    content: {x: '', y: 0},
    using: 'x', // now it can be only 'x' or 'y', and IDE will suggest it
};
```

Check it out on the [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgEIHsAeyDeBYAKGWQXXAnAC5dDjiBndAWwjAAtQBza%20sKLgNy1kAXyFFkAV3pdqAawgBPdDDRYA2gHJS5cJoC6A5AHpjyEOgDuyYGGRkANouRwHDqxAAmyMOmQAjFE1GFnYuTUIRQkIdXgCsagxsAF4aCWIdSCo0ulzkENYOEG5kTU0AGmFiEUr0qRli6mDmQvDasWiCUEhYRBQAcQpoYAQkgB4AFQA%20HLpMijBqCfFc6VlkBWVVZcjOwm7oeCRkCYg4-DrMHj5BKuRFahBJJkCocSiCGLI4ziH%20UYSyEGIGGAMwkzOYBmqQuuXm2RwV1KFXu1AADDU7mtGqVMCjTPYQE5cZp7FBSooIgQOgQgA).